# servlets execute smoothly but record does not insert into mysql table

Tags: jsp, servlets, mysql-python

1. My application has one jsp file for form design to get student details. (jsp ok) (mysql back end with 6columns)
2. I passed all the form values from jsp file servlet file. The servlet also receive all form values from jsp file
3. excuteUpdate() method is used for record insertion into mysql.
4. My servlet file executes without any error but record not inserted into table. While i debugged my application it say sql state value is null in my exception list.
5. (mysql back end with 6columns)rollno,name,dept,mark1,mark2,mark3

//this is my servlet code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 *
 * @author CSE
 */
public class AddStudent extends HttpServlet 
{

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
   {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello");

        try 
        {
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//MySQL database connection
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javademo?"+"user=root&password=");
                int rollno = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtrollno"));
                String name = request.getParameter("txtname");
                String department = request.getParameter("txtdept");
                int mark1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtmark1"));
                int mark2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtmark2"));
                int mark3 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtmark3"));

                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into student(rollno,name,department,mark1,mark2,mark3)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
                ps.setInt(1,rollno);
                ps.setString(2,name);
                ps.setString(3,department);
                ps.setInt(4,mark1);
                ps.setInt(5,mark2);
                ps.setInt(6,mark3);

                ps.executeUpdate();
                con.commit();

                ps.close();
                con.close();
                out.print(name);
              out.print("\n Record inserted successfully");  
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                System.out.println("End");
            }

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your exception here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not appended password in this line, chances of connection not established.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javademo?"+"user=root&password=");
```